# Getx not working correctly with firebase dynamic linking

Tags: deep-linking, flutter-getx

I have a project that uses getX and initialRoute is "/root".

```
runApp(
GetMaterialApp.router(
  title: "Application",
  getPages: AppPages.routes,
  routeInformationParser: GetInformationParser(
    initialRoute: Routes.ROOT,
  ),
),
```

I'm trying to use firebase dynamic linking to open app when click/open link.
When I run app from IDE (not by open link), the "GetInformationParser route location" is "/root" and everything goes correctly, but when I kill app and opens with the link (eg: https://myapp.com/ABC123) so the "GetInformationParser route location" is "/ABC123" and I get the error "Bad state: No element" with black screen. If I change link to "https://myapp.com/root" the app runs ok, but I have to create and use data from the link so I can't just use "https://myapp.com/root".
If someone can help me understand the issue, that would be great.

Comment: hello @Hoang Phuc, did you found any answer ? or how you fixed this ? I'm facing same using GetX and firebase dynamicLinks ?

Comment: I'm fixing it temporarily by overriding the position value in the GetInformationParser so it doesn't pick up the value from the link anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly. I faced a similar problem, but I didn't receive any error messages.

Instead, when I opened a dynamic link it would navigate me to a named page with the path of the link as in your example it would transfer me to a page route of `ABC123` directly, before even triggering the onLink function from the FirebaseDynamicLinks.

So I always ended up on the start page. which had a routing of `'/'`, so i changed it to `'/startPage'` and it worked for me. turns out that maybe some routing names are reserved.

So try to add initialRoute value as something like `'/startPage'` and make sure you don't have in your routes a page with a named route of `'/'` or any possibly reserved names.
this answer helped me solve my problem you can check it out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69458347/9986601